# momentjs startOf does not work on existing date object

Tags: momentjs

I'm trying to use moment to get the start of a day.  I get different results with the following:

```
moment().startOf('day'); //good
moment(new Date()).startOf('day'); //this does not work!
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y1of77wx/

The practical case is that I'm doing this in a function that takes in a date object as an argument:

```
function doWork(dt) {
   return moment(dt).startOf('day');
}
```

I'm sure the solution is simple but I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to display the value of a moment object.

As the [Internal Properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) guide states:

> Moment objects have several internal properties that are prefixed with `_`.
>
> The most commonly viewed internal property is the `_d` property that holds the JavaScript Date that Moment wrappers. Frequently, developers are confused by console output of the value of `_d`.
>
> ...
>
> To print out the value of a Moment, use `.format()`, `.toString()` or `.toISOString()`

Here a snippet showing the correct results:

```js
console.log(moment().startOf('day').format());
console.log(moment(new Date()).startOf('day').format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's interesting, it does the work properly, but the display is wrong.  If I log the unix timestamp I can indeed see that it changes.

Comment: @jhilden the output is consistent even if I log unix timestamp (using [`unix()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/)). Do you see any other issue? Which _display_ is wrong?