# Momentjs add doesn't work

Tags: momentjs

```
 var startDate = moment("2017-06-30 00:00 +0000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z");
 var endDate = startDate.clone();
 endDate.add(2, 'days');
 console.log('startDate', startDate);
 console.log('endDate', endDate);
```

I'm trying to add 2 days to the startdate but the endDate remains the same as the startdate. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44812821/4131048). You have to use [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to show moment value.

Comment: indeed, when I add .format in the console.log it shows a different date. I was checking the _i property which remained the same weirdly enough. TY!

Comment: Glad to help! :) I think that posting the same answer here is not the best thing to do, maybe this answer could be maked as duplicate of the linked one.

Answer (score 1):

To add days you can simpley use `moment().add(2)` here 2 is the number of days you wish to add

```js
 var startDate = moment("2017-06-30 00:00 +0000", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z");
 var endDate = startDate.clone();
 endDate.add(2); // or use endDate.add(2, 'day')
 console.log('startDate', startDate);
 console.log('endDate', endDate);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

If you like to add months or year just give the second parameter as months or years

```js
 var startDate = moment(); // assign today
 console.log('After 2 days:', startDate.add(2, 'days')); // startDate.add(2, 'day') 
 console.log('After 2 months:', moment().add(2, 'months')); // or startDate.add(2, 'month') 
 console.log('After 2 years:', moment().add(2, 'years')); // or startDate.add(2, 'year')
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```