# Failing to increment date with moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Well, I just can't increment a date with moment.js. I get a javascript date object in my code, wrap it into `moment` function, calculate the amount of hours I need to add to the initial date and after I use `.add` method nothing happens. Tried doing something like `currentTime.add(2, 'hours')`, that didn't work as well.  What am I doing incorrectly?

```
const currentTime = moment(ioc.get<Main.IArchiveManager>("ArchiveManager").getCurrentDate());
const speed = this.getData().speed;
const distance = this.calcDistanceFromPrevPoint(initialPoint,prevPoint);
const timeToReachPoint = (distance / speed) * 60;
const estimatedTime = currentTime.add(timeToReachPoint, 'hours');
debugger;
return estimatedTime;
```

this is a screenshot from my devtool so you know what is going on: [image]

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong? What was the original value of `currentTime`?

Comment: You know that `add()` modifies the object in place, it doesn't return a new object, right?

Comment: You have to use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to show value of moment objects. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44812821/4131048) for issue related to the way the values is printed in the console.

Comment: VincenzoC, thanks, now I see the correct value. That was quite counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) (or [`.toString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-string/) or [`.toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/)) to display the value of a moment object.

Note that:

- moment objects are mutable, so calling `add` will change the original object, if you need you can use the [`clone()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/) method
- Do not use [Internal properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) (prefixed with `_`)

Your code is fine, you are just logging moment object the wrong way:

```js
const currentTime = moment();
console.log(currentTime.format())
const speed = 0.1//this.getData().speed;
const distance = 20.56;// this.calcDistanceFromPrevPoint(initialPoint,prevPoint);
const timeToReachPoint = (distance / speed) * 60;
const estimatedTime = currentTime.add(timeToReachPoint, 'hours');
console.log(estimatedTime.format())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything is working as expected. You are logging the value of `currentTime` **after** it got changed. Remember that `.add()` changes the value of the object, it does not return a copy, but the object itself (for better chaining). See my example, you'll see that the came console.log, called twice but at different timings displays the values you'd expect.

```js
var time = moment(new Date());
console.log(time);
time.add(2,'h');
console.log(time)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: While you highlighted that moment objects are mutable, if I open console and then run your snippet I'll have the same output of the OP. Please use `format()`, `toString()` or `toISOString()` to show moment object value, as I suggested in my answer (and in the [Internal Properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) guide).

Comment: OP's problem was not about the display but more about the fact that they thought it wasn't adding as wanted. The snippet is showing the behaviour I wanted to highlight, adding more will not increase the clarity of my point.