# MomentJS calculation and format

Tags: momentjs

I try to use MomentJS to build a progress bar for my music.

I have the last update time like : "2017-09-21T18:20:11.2734588+02:00"

I have remaining seconds like : 120

I try to add 120 seconds to the last update time and calculate the difference between last update + 120 and now.

I tried :

```
var start = moment(stateobject.LastUpdate);
var now = moment();
var end = moment(start).add(stateobject.Value.data.remaining,'seconds');
```

But end time is exactly the same as start time. It's only work if I add 120seconds to now.

I guess it's maybe something to do with format but I didn't find.

Maybe someone can help me ?

Thank

Edit :

Here the results for the codes above :

[image]

Comment: `start` is already a moment; you don't need to reinitialize it: `moment(start)`

Comment: `.add()` mutates the original moment. Maybe that's the cause. Can you show more of the code? How do you initialize them? How do you compare them?

Comment: @chazsolo thank for the tip

Comment: @dashmug this is my code, I Juste console.log the result and I saw that the results were the same for start and end.

Comment: I added an image off the results

Comment: @Furya use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) (or [`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/) or [`toString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-string/)) to display the value of moment objects. See [Internal Properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failing to increment date with moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920904/failing-to-increment-date-with-moment-js)

Comment: @VincenzoC I tried to add format('HH:MM:SS') to start but after I've got an error, start.add isn't a function

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) (or [`.toString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-string/) or [`.toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/)) to display the value of a moment object.

As general use, do not use [Internal properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) (prefixed with `_`)

> The most commonly viewed internal property is the `_d` property that holds the JavaScript Date that Moment wrappers. Frequently, developers are confused by console output of the value of `_d`. Moment uses a technique called epoch shifting that causes this property to sometimes differ from the actual date value that the Moment reflects. In particular if Moment TimeZone is in use, this property will almost never be the same as the actual value that Moment will output from its public `.format()` function. As such, the values of `_d` and any other properties prefixed with `_` should not be used for any purpose.
>
> To print out the value of a Moment, use `.format()`, `.toString()` or `.toISOString()`.

Your code is fine, you are just logging moment object the wrong way:

```js
var stateobject = {
  LastUpdate: '2017-09-21T18:20:11.2734588+02:00',
  Value: { data: {
    remaining: 120
  }}
};

var start = moment(stateobject.LastUpdate);
var now = moment();
var end = moment(start).add(stateobject.Value.data.remaining,'seconds');

console.log(start.format('HH:mm:ss'));
console.log(end.format('HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```