# Why I can't add years to a date using MomentJS into my Angular application?

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, angular-moment

I am working on an Angular application trying to use **momentJS** to add a specific number of years to a date but it seems not working.

This is my code:

```
changeGuaranteeEndDate(guaranteeDuration) {
    console.log("changeGuaranteeEndDate() START");
    console.log("GUARANTEE START DATE: " + this.newAssetForm.value.guarantee_start_date);
    console.log("GUARANTEE DURATION: " + this.newAssetForm.value.guarantee_duration);
    console.log("EVENT VAL: " + guaranteeDuration);

    this.newAssetForm.value.guarantee_duration = guaranteeDuration;
    console.log("GUARANTEE DURATION: " + this.newAssetForm.value.guarantee_duration);

    let myMoment: moment.Moment = moment(this.newAssetForm.value.guarantee_start_date);
    console.log("myMoment: ", myMoment);

    let myMoment2 = myMoment;
    myMoment2.add(3, 'y')

    console.log("myMoment2: ", myMoment2);
}
```

So basivally I am creating the **myMoment** object starting from the date defined into **this.newAssetForm.value.guarantee_start_date**.

Then I am trying to create a new **myMoment2** object starting from **myMoment** and I am adding 3 years to this object. Finnally I print it

The problem is that in the Chrome console I obtain the following output:

```
myMoment:  
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: Fri Jan 29 2021 13:04:29 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale), _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
_d: Mon Jan 29 2024 13:04:29 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale) {}
_i: Fri Jan 29 2021 13:04:29 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale) {}
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: ƒ, …}
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
__proto__: Object

myMoment2:  
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: Fri Jan 29 2021 13:04:29 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale), _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
_d: Mon Jan 29 2024 13:04:29 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale) {}
_i: Fri Jan 29 2021 13:04:29 GMT+0100 (Ora standard dell’Europa centrale) {}
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: false
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, ordinal: ƒ, …}
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
__proto__: Object
```

The problems is that, as you can see in the previous output, it seems that the years was not added to the original**myMoment** object.

What is wrong with my code? What am I missing? How can I correctly add years to my original **myMoment** object?

Comment: have you tried to `console.log( this.newAssetForm.value.guarantee_start_date )` ? what does it returns?

Comment: I just created a codepen with nearly the exact same logic and it works there perfectly: https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/rNWNyvy?editors=1111

Comment: I believe the code is just working fine. The only problem is that you are creating a shalow copy of moment object. and the on addition of year you are seeing changes in both the variables. You can do `let myMoment2 = myMoment.clone();` and then do the addition. you will see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me.... you can test it clicking on `Run code Snippet` below.

You can try to use the same loaded lib of my example: src moment.min.js

```js
function changeGuaranteeEndDate(guaranteeDuration) {
    console.log("changeGuaranteeEndDate() START");
    console.log("GUARANTEE START DATE: " + this.newAssetForm.value.guarantee_start_date);
    console.log("GUARANTEE DURATION: " + this.newAssetForm.value.guarantee_duration);
    console.log("EVENT VAL: " + guaranteeDuration);

    this.newAssetForm.value.guarantee_duration = guaranteeDuration;
    console.log("GUARANTEE DURATION: " + this.newAssetForm.value.guarantee_duration);

    let myMoment = moment(this.newAssetForm.value.guarantee_start_date);

    console.log("myMoment: ", myMoment);

    let myMoment2 = myMoment;
    myMoment2.add(3, 'y')

    console.log("myMoment2: ", myMoment2);
}

// This is just for Testing the function... and mocking object
changeGuaranteeEndDate.apply({
  newAssetForm:{
    value:{
      guarantee_start_date:new Date(),
      guarantee_duration:undefined
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script       src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need `format()` to display the value of the moment object. Basically the problem is the initial value you pass to it. Read more about it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811933/momentjs-startof-does-not-work-on-existing-date-object/44812821#44812821). So your last console log should look like this:

```
console.log("myMoment2: ", myMoment2.format());
```

Comment: Please avoid answering question by redirecting user to answer of another question. You can do it in comments.